# Given an integer $n$, can the fraction $\frac{2n}{4n-1}$ be simplified?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an integer $n$, can the fraction $$\frac{2n}{4n-1}$$ be simplified?

I am not sure how I can show whether this is true or not or even begin to investigate it without writing out lots of terms.

Of course, the top is even and the denominator is odd but that's not sufficient to make any conclusion... I was thinking perhaps that $4n-1$ is not divisible by $2$ or by $n$ but then if $n$ is not prime, that argument doesn't work I don't think.

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$.

Comment: For $~d \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ if $~d~$ divides $~2n,~$ then $~d~$ divides $~4n,~$ which implies that $~d~$ does not divide $~4n-1.$

Comment: $$2\cdot 2n - (4n-1) = 1$$ If $d$ divides both the numerator $2n$ and the denominator $(4n-1)$, then $d$ also divides the RHS $1$. So $d$ can only be $1$.

Comment: If $d\neq 1$ divides $2n$ then $d$ divides $4n$ but $d$ doesn't divide $-1$ therefore $d$ doesn't divide $4n-1$.

Comment: That is $\frac{2n}d =k \implies \frac{4n-1}d= \frac{4n}d-\frac 1d =2k-\frac 1d$.

Comment: By the linked dupe $\,\gcd(a,ab-1) = \gcd(a,-1) = 1.\ $ OP is case $\,a,b = 2n,2\ \ $

Comment: When you say "can be simplified" are you asking if $\frac {2n}{4n-1}$ is always in "lowest terms"?  Or are you asking if we can rewrite $\frac {2n}{4n-1}$ as something else (maybe $\frac 2{4 -\frac 1n}$)?  Or do you mean something else entirely.

Comment: I suppose the easiest "explain as though I were 5" answer would be: Whatever (other than one) can divide $n$ will divide $4n$ and so will not divide $4n-1$.  And $2$ doesn't divide $4n-1$.  So (other than one) nothing that divides the numerator will divide the denominator.  So the numerator and denominator have no factors (other than one) in common.

Comment: "but then if n is not prime, that argument doesn't work I don't think."  It doesn't work as easily but it *does* work.  $n$, and all its divisors divide $4n$, so $n$ and all if its non-trivial (not $1$) divisors *fail* to divide $4n-1$.  Argument works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\text{gcd}(2n, 4n-1) = 1$, you cannot.

Comment: But why is this the case?

Comment: Because if you want to simplify the fraction, you should divide the numerator and denominator with the same number. If a great common divisor is 1, that means that you can only divide the numerator and denominator simultaneously with 1.

Comment: Sorry I meant, why is $gcd(2n, 4n-1) = 1$?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Use twice my hint above: $\gcd(4n-1,2n)=\gcd(2n-1,2n)=\gcd(-1,2n)=1.$

Comment: If $2n$ has a non-trivial (not equal to $1$) divisor, then $4n$ has the same divisor. But after subtracting $1$ we lose that divisor.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the numerator and denominator have a common factor $d$. Then $d$ divides both $2n$ and $4n-1$, and so $d$ also divides
$$2\cdot(2n)-(4n-1)=1,$$
and so $d=\pm1$. This shows that the fraction cannot be simplified any further.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: @BillDubuque I disagree with the assessment that this is a duplicate.